# How to pass JS object between controllers in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am using ASP.NET MVC, I have a JavaScript object and I need to save it until I redirect the user to login screen in order to authenticate him and then return back to the same page with the JS object to fill the form controls using JavaScript.

So what is the best technique I can use to achieve this scenario and to secure my sensitive data?

Comment: You'd create a C# class to back your JavaScript object. Pass it into your controller, convert it to the C# class, then pass it around your application. Serialize it back to JavaScript before returning back to the client side.

Comment: how to pass it around my application you mean in session or something like that ?

Comment: Yes, `Session` is one way. `TempData` is another way.

Comment: but is session a good way to save sensitive data? and if so why i can't use session in java script without passing it to the controller?

Comment: In this scenario, you can't use TempData as you're going back and forth with different requests. So your first option would be Sessions. Another option could be holding an encrypted version of the files JSON in client-side, (using javascript's sessionStorage) and then post it back to the next page and decrypt it. I mean Encryption/Decryption could be done on the server. This method works well if your object size is not that large.

Comment: You can with local storage in html 5 -> http://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html5_webstorage.asp